# Most efficient way to search and replace multiple patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a script that should disable PasswordAuthentication in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
So I'm trying to do this with sed. In our environment it can be multiple patterns.
So I have 3 sed commands in my script, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to replace this.

I'm actually looking for to replace either `#PasswordAuthentication yes`, `PasswordAuthentication yes`or `PasswordAuthentication no`.
Is there a better way to do so? 
Is this the cleanest way to do as well, or should I officially add an if statement to it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you did not post your code and your current sed approaches. A good question would require those things

Comment: My apologies:

sed -i -- "s|PermitRootLogin yes|PermitRootLogin no|g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config

`sed -i -- "s|#PermitRootLogin yes|PermitRootLogin no|g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and

`sed -i -- "s|#PermitRootLogin no|PermitRootLogin no|g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single regexp pattern:

```
sed 's/^\s*#\?PasswordAuthentication\s*\(yes\|no\)\s*$/YOUR_REPLACEMENT/'
```

The [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can be read as follows:

```
 ^ - matches the start of line
 \s* - matches any (0 or more) amount of whitespace characters
 #\? - matches 0 or 1 `#` characters
 PasswordAuthentication - matches a literal text string, as is
 \s* - (see above)
 (yes\|no\) - matches either `yes` or `no`
 \s* - (see above)
 $ - matches the end of line
```

> Matches whitespace characters (spaces and tabs). Newlines embedded in the pattern/hold spaces will also match:

This will match:

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and replace any of these lines with YOUR_REPLACEMENT

Comment: That's perfect! If it's not too much to ask would you mind explaining step by step how it works and how it's build so I can learn from it, and do it myself next time?

Comment: Thank you so much @zeppelin, that makes it even clearer. 

Just one thing, the `matches the start/end of line`... Doesn't sed to that automatically, or?

Comment: @Florius 
>Doesn't sed to that automatically, or?
No, it will match a pattern in the middle of a string too, unless you explicitly instruct it that you want to match the whole line.